# Loop Through All Subfolders - VBA - Queue method

Tags: vba, excel

I've made use of Cor_blimey's queue method to write all the folders and subfolders of a drive to an excel sheet, as follows:

```
Public Sub NonRecursiveMethod()
    Dim fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, oFile, queue As Collection

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set queue = New Collection
    queue.Add fso.GetFolder("your folder path variable") 'obviously replace

    Do While queue.Count > 0
        Set oFolder = queue(queue.count)
        queue.Remove(queue.count) 'dequeue
        '...insert any folder processing code here...'
       '*...(Here I write the name of the folder to the excel sheet)*.
        For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
            queue.Add oSubfolder 'enqueue
        Next oSubfolder
        For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
       '...insert any file processing code here...
       Next oFile
    Loop

End Sub
```

I've tried the "LIFO" version (as above) and the "FIFO" version, but neither of them produces a standard alphabetical listing. The above version lists the drive in exact reverse alphabetical order, and the "FIFO" version produces a list in normal alphabetical order, but it lists only the first-level folders, then starts again and lists all the second-level folders, again in alphabetical order, then the third level of folders, again starting over from "A", etc. As a result, the subfolders are not listed under their parent folder.

Does anyone know what I can do to get a standard tree structure, in alphabetical order by folder and subfolder name?

TIA

Les

Update: for some reason I can't manage to show all the comments on this thread or write a new comment. But I wanted to thank everybody, in particular @Rosenfeld, and say that I'm eager to try the solution using `dir` but am currently swamped with work. I'll report back in a few days when I get a chance to stumble around.

Comment: Can you provide your code in full? It looks like you have removed some where you are actually writing the data to the sheet. Without seeing the code though, and if you already have it in reverse alphabetical order you could just load your collection into a new collection (reversed order) before processing. Something like `For each Item in Collection : NewCollection.Add Item : Next` (this is a really simplified example of course).

Comment: I think you can achieve that using the optional parameters `After` or `Before` when you Add the subfolders.

Comment: The fastest way to list all folders and subfolders would be by using the `cmd` interface `dir` function.  There are a lot of ways you can format the output, using simple switches in the command.  Experiment in the CMD window until you get the output you want, and then use the `WshShell.Run` method to run it.

Comment: Provide an example of exactly how you want your output formatted.

Comment: @BrandonBarney Thanks to everyone who's replied. Looking over the code - which as I said I simply "stole" from an earlier thread - I get the impression that the basic problem is that there's no hierarchization. That is, the code as is writes each level of subdirectories to the sheet separately, rather than writing each subdirectory, then its subdirectories (if any), then that subdirectory's subdirectories, and so on. (Sorry for using "directory" instead of "folder" for those who might prefer the latter.)

I'm now looking for a way to queue all levels of subdirectories of each subdirectory, in

Comment: @RonRosenfeld To answer your question, I'd like for the output to the sheet to look like the results of a `tree` command.

Comment: @Lestrad The real problem, if I understand correctly, is how you are getting the items out of the queue. While my approach solves the problem in a different way, you could accomplish the task (organized alphabetically) by looping through your queue in the opposite direction. The problem here though is, since you copied and pasted the code, you need to get to a point of understanding the *what* and *why* of the code, so you can become comfortable in modifying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'd like for the output to the sheet to look like the results of a tree command*

Seems to me the simplest would be to just use the `Tree` command.

Here is one way, but the details could certainly be changed:

- Execute a Tree command on the base folder
- Write the output to some text file (location and name specified in the code)
- Open the file as a text file in Excel
- Split into columns on the vertical bar (Unicode character 9474) that the Tree command uses to differentiate levels
- I use the `WSH.Run` method as that allows the `CMD` window to be easily hidden

  - One could use the `WSH.Exec` method to pipe the output directly to a VBA variable, but it is much harder to hide the `CMD` window (meaning, in another application, I've not been able to) :-)

One could also Import the text file into the same workbook instead of opening a new file.  I will leave that exercise to you if you choose to do it.

```
Option Explicit
'set referennce to Windows Script Host Object Model
Sub DirTree()
    Dim sBaseFolder As String, sTempFile As String
    Dim WSH As WshShell
    Dim sCMD As String
    Dim lErrCode As Long
    

'Many ways to set starting point
sBaseFolder = Environ("HOMEDRIVE") & "\"
sTempFile = Environ("TEMP") & "\Tree.txt"

'Command line
sCMD = "CMD /c tree """ & sBaseFolder & """ > """ & sTempFile & """"

Set WSH = New WshShell
lErrCode = WSH.Run(sCMD, xlHidden, True)

If Not lErrCode = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error in execution: Code - " & lErrCode
Else
    'Open the file
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=sTempFile, Origin:=xlMSDOS, _
        StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False _
        , Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:=ChrW(&H2502), _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1))
End If
    
End Sub
```

Here is a screenshot of the beginning of the output when run on my `C:` drive

[image]

**EDIT:**  Since you now mention that you want the links to be clickable, an approach using `dir` would probably be simpler, especially since you can provide arguments to the `dir` command that will result in full paths being returned.

I used a class module so as to have a User Defined Object, which would have the necessary information; and a dictionary of these objects after appropriate filtering.

I chose to display merely the folder name in the cell, but the the screen tip will show the full path.

Note the References that need to be set (in the code).  Also note that the class module must be renamed: *cTree*

**EDIT 2:** The Regular and Class modules were edited to allow for optional listing of the files. Note that the macro now has an argument, so it must be called from another macro or from the immediate window, to include the argument.  (The argument could also be obtained from an Input box, user form, etc, but I did it this way for now because it is simpler.

I did not add hyperlinks for the files, thinking it would get confusing as different programs and dialogs (other than the file explorer) would be opening depending on the extension.

### Class Module

---

```
Option Explicit
'Rename Class Module:  cTree

Private pFullPath As String
Private pFolderName As String
Private pLevel As Long
Private pFile As String
Private pFiles As Dictionary

Public Property Get FullPath() As String
    FullPath = pFullPath
End Property
Public Property Let FullPath(Value As String)
    pFullPath = Value
End Property

Public Property Get FolderName() As String
    FolderName = pFolderName
End Property
Public Property Let FolderName(Value As String)
    pFolderName = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Level() As Long
    Level = pLevel
End Property
Public Property Let Level(Value As Long)
    pLevel = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Files() As Dictionary
    Set Files = pFiles
End Property
Public Function ADDfile(Value As String)
    pFiles.Add Value, Value
End Function
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pFiles = New Dictionary
    pFiles.CompareMode = TextCompare
End Sub
```

---

### Regular Module

---

```
Option Explicit
'Set reference to Windows Script Host Object Model
'                 Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Sub GetDirList(bInclFiles As Boolean)
    Const sDIRargs As String = " /A-S-L-H /S"
    
    Dim sBaseFolder As String, sTempFile As String
    Dim WSH As WshShell
    Dim sCMD As String
    Dim lErrCode As Long
    
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject, TS As TextStream
    Dim S As String, sFN As String
    Dim V As Variant, W As Variant
    Dim I As Long
    
    Dim lMaxLevel As Long
    Dim lMinLevel As Long
    
    Dim dctTrees As Dictionary, cT As cTree
    Dim wsRes As Worksheet
    Dim vRes As Variant, rRes As Range
    
'Add worksheet if needed
On Error Resume Next
Set wsRes = Worksheets("TreeLink")
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        Set wsRes = Worksheets.Add
        wsRes.Name = "TreeLink"
    End If
On Error GoTo 0
Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

    
'Many ways to set starting point
sBaseFolder = Environ("HOMEDRIVE") & "\"
sTempFile = Environ("TEMP") & "\DirList.txt"

'CommandLine
sCMD = "CMD /c dir """ & sBaseFolder & """" & sDIRargs & " > " & sTempFile

Set WSH = New WshShell
lErrCode = WSH.Run(sCMD, xlHidden, True)

If Not lErrCode = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error in execution: Code - " & lErrCode
    Stop
    
Else
    'Read in the relevant data
    Set dctTrees = New Dictionary
    Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile(sTempFile, ForReading, False, TristateUseDefault)
    lMaxLevel = 0
    
    V = Split(TS.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
    
    For I = 0 To UBound(V)
        Do Until V(I) Like " Directory of *"
            If I = UBound(V) Then Exit For
            I = I + 1
        Loop
        Set cT = New cTree
            S = Mid(V(I), 15)
            
            'Can exclude certain directories at this point
            'To exclude all that start with a dot:
            If Not S Like "*\.*" Then
            
            With cT
                .FullPath = S
                .FolderName = Right(S, Len(S) - InStrRev(S, "\"))
                .Level = Len(S) - Len(Replace(S, "\", ""))
                
                lMaxLevel = IIf(lMaxLevel > .Level, lMaxLevel, .Level)
                
                dctTrees.Add Key:=S, Item:=cT
                
                I = I + 1
                
                'Only run for file list
                If bInclFiles = True Then
                Do
                    sFN = V(I)
                    If Not sFN Like "*<DIR>*" _
                            And sFN <> "" Then
                        'add the files
                        dctTrees(S).ADDfile Mid(sFN, 40)
                    End If
                    I = I + 1
                Loop Until V(I) Like "*# File(s)*"
                End If
                
            End With
            
            End If 'End of directory exclusion "if" statement
            
    Next I
    
    lMinLevel = dctTrees(dctTrees.Keys(0)).Level
    
    I = 0
    With rRes.Resize(columnsize:=lMaxLevel + 1).EntireColumn
        .Clear
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each V In dctTrees.Keys
        Set cT = dctTrees(V)
        With cT
            I = I + 1
            rRes.Worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=rRes(I, .Level - lMinLevel + 1), _
                Address:="File:///" & .FullPath, _
                ScreenTip:=.FullPath, _
                TextToDisplay:=.FolderName
                
            For Each W In .Files.Keys
                I = I + 1
                rRes(I, .Level - lMinLevel + 2) = W
            Next W
        
        End With
    Next V
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End If
End Sub
```

---

### Results without File Listing

[image]

### Results with File Listing

[image]

Comment: Rosenfield Admittedly what I am about to suggest is over my level of expertise and experience, but couldnt we go one step further by using VBA to write a shell script, or a batch file. If I am not mistaken, both would allow for hiding of the CMD window.

Comment: @BrandonBarney I haven't experimented with that.  But for single line commands such as we have here, what would be the advantage?

Comment: It is more of a 'we could do it to go one step further' over an 'this would be more ideal'. Really, it would just prevent users from getting concerned if they see a CMD window pop up and run a command. Beyond that though, no real advantage at all (and depending on the application/environment it could be a disadvantage).

Comment: Since the `Run` method can be used and will hide the CMD window, I don't see any real advantage.  Not writing to the file system is a potential advantage of piping the output of the command directly to a VBA variable, but a batch file would have to be written to the file system anyway.

Comment: @BrandonBarney And there are methods of hiding the CMD window using Windows API calls, even when using the WSH.Exec method, but I haven't looked at that as I've not had the requirement.

Comment: My mistake, I completely misread your line about how one could use `WSH.Exec` and, for some reason, thought your current approach wasnt hiding the CMD window. Ignore me.

Comment: I fell back on the recursive method and was able to get what I wanted (I can post the code if someone wants it) - but it remains to be seen how it will perform on a root drive with a big, deep tree structure.

Comment: @Lestrad I would guess that if performance time is an issue, the tree command as I showed will work much faster.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I tried this and it works. I'd have never thought of using the vertical-line character like that. And it's very fast. The problem is that I want to be able to click on the cell and open the corresponding folder. For that, might I be able to adapt your approach, but using the `dir`command? Anyway thanks!

Comment: @Lestrad I must have missed the requirement for clickable links in your original question.  You wrote you wanted it to look like the output of the `Tree` command, so that is what this shows. I'm not at my working computer, so really cannot advise the best way to add clickable links and still have your desired output format.  i'll take a look later.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I have to apologize - I didn't in fact mention that I wanted clickable links, or even that I wanted the entire path of each folder and subfolder. Making a clickable link is easy enough - I have a little macro that creates and then Follows a link from a path.
As I say, I was able to get a tree-like display, but it's rather slow. I'm working on adapting your approach using `dir` instead of `tree`.

Comment: @Lestrad Interesting problem.  I edited my response to provide an answer that creates links and might be useful.

Comment: @Lestrad **You keep adding specifications that were not in your original post**. I suggest, as a first step to figure out how to do what you want, that you open a CMD window, and experiment with the `dir` command until you get the arguments that will produce the output you require.  And `dir /?` will bring up a help page to explain the arguments (or use a Google search). (Had you done so, you would not even have tried the arguments you did).  You will also need to understand the code in order to modify it. See Chip Pearson's [Introduction to Classes](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I adapted your solution and tried it and it works incredibly fast compared to the approach I was using. My only question: how to get it to display files as well? (In my current approach I pop up a dialogue which sets a Boolean variable corresponding to "Show files too"/"Show folders only".) I tried changing the `sDIRargs` constant for the command-line switches to " /O-S /S" instead of  "/AD-S-L-H /S", but it still shows only the folders. Any help would be appreciated as I'm not sure I really understand all your code yet. But anyway thanks and Bravo!

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks and sorry. The help file "/?" for the `dir` command isn't the simplest thing in the world to figure out, but please don't think I didn't study it. I'll look for a bit more user-friendly guide. Thanks very much for the link, since I clearly need to study that too.

Comment: @Lestrad *thoughts*: Listing Files you may run over the row limit of an  excel sheet; why reproduce the File Explorer in Excel?; to get layout, might be easier to use the `Tree` command with the `show files` option, and reconstruct the full path in code.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  Thanks. I'm now implementing a second array-dictionary for the filenames. We'll see how it goes. Then I want to write in a time counter to write the time in the sheet at the start and at the end, in both approaches, to have an accurate idea of how fast your approach really is. Not sure what you mean about `Tree` and showing files; need to look into it.

Comment: @Lestrad With regard to the dictionary of files, you could make that a property of the cTree object; then it would be tied to the relevant folder.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld That's what I ended up doing. I just added a FileName property to cTree. Then I changed the Filters to exclude everything **but** the lines with the Folder name and the file names. Then I added code to figure out if the current item being read is a file or a folder while populating the dictionary. Then when creating the hyperlinks I increased the Level property by 1 to indent the filenames under each folder, and also changed the font color of the filenames. So far it's working fine - thanks to you.
Now I need to try to implement the same thing using `tree`...

Comment: @Lestrad If you have it working using `dir`, why bother with `Tree`?

Comment: @Lestrad BTW, I used `/A-S-L-H /S` for the `dir` args; developed the folder list by looking for the `Directory of ...` strings, and detected files of that folder because, in the listing below it, there was no `<DIR>` entry.  I figured the levels as originally; made a dictionary of file names as a property of the folder, and indented one extra when printing. If you like, I can add that to my answer.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes; I'd love to see that if it's no trouble. The way I did it was to just loop through the lines in the array V until I hit ":\" and assign the corresponding line to a Cur(rent)Folder variable. 
Meanwhile I added code to write the starting and ending time to a text file. It's **fast**.
My `dir` switches are `/a /on /S /n`. I'll try your and see what it does.

Comment: @Lestrad I'll edit my post with the modified code (and a new screenshot) later today. It actually takes longer to add the hyperlinks than to run the `dir` command.

Comment: @Lestrad Modified code posted.  And could you please mark my response as the **Answer**.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are using a non-recursion method, but admittedly I wanted to try my hand at using recursion to solve the task (particularly for anyone who may need this in the future).

Note: I am not certain that the Scripting.FileSystem Folders/Files collections are always alphabetical so I am assuming they are in this case, but I *could* be mistaken.

From brief tests I am not noticing any kind of performance issue with recursion though, depending on the directory size, there certainly could be one.

Finally, the 'CleanOutput' argument in the main Function is used to determine if hierarchy relationships are displayed in the output.

### Method Used to Test/Output

```
Sub Test()
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    Dim Folder As Scripting.Folder
    Set Folder = fso.GetFolder("C:")

    Dim Test As Variant
    Test = GetDirectoryFromScriptingFolder(Folder, True)

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Test, 1), UBound(Test, 2)).value = Test
End Sub
```

### Main Function

```
Private Function GetDirectoryFromScriptingFolder(ByVal InputFolder As Scripting.Folder, Optional CleanOutput As Boolean = False) As Variant
    ' Uses recursion to return an organized hierarchy that represents files/folders in the input directory
    Dim CurrentRow As Long
    CurrentRow = 1

    Dim CurrentColumn As Long
    CurrentColumn = 1

    Dim OutputDirectory As Variant
    ReDim OutputDirectory(1 To GetDirectoryLength(InputFolder), 1 To GetDirectoryDepth(InputFolder))

    WriteFolderHierarchy InputFolder, OutputDirectory, CurrentRow, CurrentColumn, CleanOutput

    ' Adjust current column so that files in the parent directory are properly indented
    WriteFileHierarchy InputFolder, OutputDirectory, CurrentRow, CurrentColumn + 1, CleanOutput

    GetDirectoryFromScriptingFolder = OutputDirectory
End Function
```

### Functions Used in Recursion

```
Private Sub WriteFolderHierarchy(ByVal InputFolder As Scripting.Folder, ByRef InputHierarchy As Variant, ByRef CurrentRow As Long, ByVal CurrentColumn As Long, ByVal CleanOutput As Boolean)
    If Not IsArray(InputHierarchy) Then Exit Sub

    InputHierarchy(CurrentRow, CurrentColumn) = InputFolder.Name
    CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1

    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim SubFolder As Folder
    For Each SubFolder In InputFolder.SubFolders
        ' Use recursion to write the files/folders of each subfolder to the directory
        StartRow = CurrentRow
        WriteFolderHierarchy SubFolder, InputHierarchy, CurrentRow, CurrentColumn + 1, CleanOutput
        WriteFileHierarchy SubFolder, InputHierarchy, CurrentRow, CurrentColumn + 2, CleanOutput

        If CleanOutput Then
            For StartRow = StartRow To CurrentRow
                InputHierarchy(StartRow, CurrentColumn) = "||"
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub WriteFileHierarchy(ByVal InputFolder As Scripting.Folder, ByRef InputHierarchy As Variant, ByRef CurrentRow As Long, ByVal CurrentColumn As Long, ByVal CleanOutput As Boolean)
    If Not IsArray(InputHierarchy) Then Exit Sub

    Dim SubFile As File
    For Each SubFile In InputFolder.Files
        ' Write the Files to the Hierarchy
        InputHierarchy(CurrentRow, CurrentColumn) = SubFile.Name
        If CleanOutput Then InputHierarchy(CurrentRow, CurrentColumn - 1) = "--"
        CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

### Helper Functions (Depth and Length)

```
Private Function GetDirectoryLength(ByVal InputFolder As Scripting.Folder) As Long
    Dim TotalLength As Long

    ' Include a base of 1 to account for the input folder
    TotalLength = 1 + InputFolder.Files.Count

    Dim SubFolder As Scripting.Folder
    For Each SubFolder In InputFolder.SubFolders
        ' Add 1 to the total to account for the subfolder.
        TotalLength = TotalLength + GetDirectoryLength(SubFolder)
    Next

    GetDirectoryLength = TotalLength
End Function

Private Function GetDirectoryDepth(ByVal InputFolder As Scripting.Folder) As Long
    Dim TotalDepth As Long

    Dim SubFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim MaxDepth As Long
    Dim NewDepth As Long
    For Each SubFolder In InputFolder.SubFolders
        NewDepth = GetDirectoryDepth(SubFolder)

        If NewDepth > MaxDepth Then
            MaxDepth = NewDepth
        End If
    Next

    If MaxDepth = 0 Then MaxDepth = 1

    ' Add 1 for the Parent Directory
    GetDirectoryDepth = MaxDepth + 2
End Function
```

What is essentially happening is this:

- We take an input Folder and determine the dimensions of the hierarchy
  for that file
- Next, we define an output array using those dimensions.
- Using a row counter and column counter, we allow the recursion functions to write their recursive results directly to the hierarchy
- This hierarchy is returned, and the main routine puts this straight to the sheet

### Next Steps that You Could Take

I noticed a few things doing this

- There is no information other than the file name, which, depending on
  the application, may make the method useless
- All files are included
  in the output, not just *important* ones (non-important files being
  temp, hidden, etc.)
- Even with the `CleanOutput` option there isn't an easy way of diagramming the relationships between parents and children.

Overall though this should suffice, depending on your needs. You can make adjustments as needed. If you have questions, just ask :).

Comment: I tested this on one of my org's network directories where the output was ~ 265,000 x 17 and it took 63 minutes so, if you are mapping a complex directory, this will be time consuming. There are process improvements that could be made (the use of DoEvents), but that will come down to how you are using this.

Comment: That seems like a long time.  I can list the 617,000 entries on my C: drive in well under one minute.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld complexity/network connection makes a difference. A C: connection will undoubtedly be faster than doing it over a network. I don't have any directories on my c drive I can use to test it that way though.

Comment: And if you mean list the 617k entries on your drove using this code then that would further the idea that it is a network issue in this case. Filling the array with the "CleanOutput' bit may play a role as well.

Comment: I would agree with that.  I have a process that I run frequently on a mapped drive that resides on my NAS.  A fraction of the number of files.  On that particular drive, on that particular network, the `CMD - dir` method finished reading the directory about 10-20 times faster than using the `FileSystemObject`.  On a directly attached drive, barely noticeable; but on the NAS drive, the time difference is on the order of 25 sec vs 7-8 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think LIFO or FIFO matters, just take a look at this idea.

```
Sub GetFilesInFolder(SourceFolderName As String)

'--- For Example:Folder Name= "D:\Folder Name\"

Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, SubFolder As Scripting.folder
Dim FileItem As Scripting.File

Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

'--- This is for displaying, whereever you want can be configured

r = 14
For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
    Cells(r, 2).Formula = r - 13
    Cells(r, 3).Formula = FileItem.Name
    Cells(r, 4).Formula = FileItem.Path
    Cells(r, 5).Formula = FileItem.Size
    Cells(r, 6).Formula = FileItem.Type
    Cells(r, 7).Formula = FileItem.DateLastModified
    Cells(r, 8).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & FileItem.Path & """,""" & "Click Here to Open" & """)"

    r = r + 1   ' next row number
Next FileItem

Set FileItem = Nothing
Set SourceFolder = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
```

End Sub

ii) User wants to get the list of all files inside a folder as well as Sub-folders
Copy and Paste the below Code and this will list down the list of all the files inside the folder as well as sub-folders. If there are other files which are there in some other Sub-folders then it will list down all files from each and Every Folders and Sub-folders.

```
Sub GetFilesInFolder(SourceFolderName As String, Subfolders As Boolean)

'--- For Example:Folder Name= "D:\Folder Name\" and Flag as Yes or No

Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, SubFolder As Scripting.folder
Dim FileItem As Scripting.File
'Dim r As Long
    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

    '--- This is for displaying, whereever you want can be configured

    r = 14
    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
        Cells(r, 2).Formula = r - 13
        Cells(r, 3).Formula = FileItem.Name
        Cells(r, 4).Formula = FileItem.Path
        Cells(r, 5).Formula = FileItem.Size
        Cells(r, 6).Formula = FileItem.Type
        Cells(r, 7).Formula = FileItem.DateLastModified
        Cells(r, 8).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & FileItem.Path & """,""" & "Click Here to Open" & """)"

        r = r + 1   ' next row number
    Next FileItem

    '--- This is the Function to go each and Every Folder and get the Files. This is a Nested-Function Calling.

    If Subfolders = True Then
        For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.Subfolders
            ListFilesInFolder SubFolder.Path, True
        Next SubFolder
    End If

    Set FileItem = Nothing
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

File Manager using Excel Macro in Excel Workbook

I have created one File Manager using the above Code. It basically fetches the list of Files from Folders and Sub-folders and list them. It fetches other details of the files as well like File Size, Last modified, path of the File, Type of the File and a hyperlink to open the file directly from the excel by clicking on that.
It looks something like below:

Here is the link to download the full Workbook.

http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2011/11/how-to-get-list-of-all-files-in-a-folder-and-sub-folders/

Click on the button that is named 'Download Now'.