# Move specific amount of (random) folders to another folder in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55531195/copy-random-25-files-from-1300-to-another-folder-with-vba?newreg=a4dcf09e3c0a43b29710651b2dbf037d), a user asked on how to copy 25 random files from a large amount of files in another folder using VBA.

My question goes in the same direction, but is a little bit different:

How can I **move** (instead of copy) a specific amount of **folders** (not files like pdf etc.) from one folder to another folder?

Some further info on my project:

- The source folder contains a varying number of folders, which itself contain one pdf-file.
- Instead of moving a specific amount of folders randomly, I would prefer to move e.g. the first 30 folders based on their alphabetic sorting (e.g. just move the first 30 folders, then in a second execution the next 30 folders from the remaining amount of folders in the source folder.

This is the code from the original post, where 25 files are copied randomly:

```
Dim FSO As Object, folder a Object, file as Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(FromPath)
Dim fList() As String, i As Long
ReDim fList(1 To folder.Files.Count)

For Each file In folder.Files
    i = i + 1
    fList(i) = file.Name
Next file

Dim copyCount As Long, fIndex As Long
copyCount = 0
Do While copyCount < 25 And copyCount < folder.Files.Count
    fIndex = Int(Rnd * folder.Files.Count) + 1
    If fList(fIndex) <> "" Then
        Set file = folder.Files(CStr(fList(fIndex)))
        file.Copy ToPath, True
        fList(fIndex) = ""    '  Mark this file as copied to prevent that it is picked a 2nd time
        copyCount = copyCount + 1
    End If
Loop
```

I successfully changed the exectuion method "file.copy ToPath, True" to "file.Move ToPath" as well as counting and saving the folder-names (instead of the file-names) in an array.

However, after executing the sub 2 times, the script does not move the folders it is supposed to do. Instead of 36 folders, it only moves 29 and so on.

I do not understand, where the problem comes from. It has to do something with the array and the index?

Thank you very much in advance! Your help is really appreciated :-)

Comment: Does the code you provided actually work? I don't see where you set `FSO`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The code posted above was actually an answer to the question on how to copy the 25 random files (see link to referred post above). It seems to be, that the user giving the answer, forgot to include "Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")", as you noticed correctly. I inserted the line of code.

Based on this info, can you or anybody else help me with rewriting this code to move (instead of copy) files :-)

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45062822/loop-through-all-subfolders-vba-queue-method) post. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the link. I looked at the question there and I am not able to transfer my project to the code posted there. Although the code in the question seems to go in the direction of my project, I do not really undestand the solution proposed in the thread. If anybody could help me out, it would be really kind :-)